# Select on table with name contains a "\"

Tags: sql

I'm trying to write a select to table with name contain "\" ?

```
select * from  TTOOs/Agents
```

Comment: so what is the problem select it.

Comment: Does it contain a / or a \ ? I'm confused...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In most databases (these include DB2, CUBRID, Derby, H2, HSQLDB, Ingres, Oracle, Postgres), you have to put quotes around your table name, i.e.

```
SELECT * FROM "TTOOs/Agents"
```

In T-SQL (SQL Server, Sybase ASE, Sybase SQL Anywhere), put brackets

```
SELECT * FROM [TTOOs/Agents]
```

In MySQL, put backticks

```
SELECT * FROM `TTOOs/Agents`
```

In any of the above cases, you'll have to correctly use upper/lower case letters!

Answer (score 0):

Try referencing your table name in brackets.

```
SELECT * FROM [TTOS/Agents]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use MySQL, use backticks to around the table name:

```
select * from `TTOOs/Agents`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
select * from [TTOOs/Agents]
```